# error: The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: flutter, dart

i know the solution is simple but im new to nullsafety and animations please help me solve this problem :

here is the code :

```
class FadeAnimation extends StatelessWidget {
  final double delay;
  final Widget child;

  FadeAnimation(this.delay, this.child);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final tween = MultiTrackTween([
      Track("opacity")
          .add(Duration(milliseconds: 500), Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0)),
      Track("translateY").add(
          Duration(milliseconds: 500), Tween(begin: -30.0, end: 0.0),
          curve: Curves.easeOut)
    ]);

    return ControlledAnimation(
      delay: Duration(milliseconds: (500 * delay).round()),
      duration: tween.duration,
      tween: tween,
      child: child,
      builderWithChild: (context, child, animation) => Opacity(
        opacity: animation["opacity"],
        child: Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0, animation["translateY"]), child: child),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the problem is with thise 2 lines

```
opacity: animation["opacity"],
```

and this one :

```
 offset: Offset(0, animation["translateY"]), child: child),
```

Note: the null operator didnt worked .
i appreciate your help inadvance .

Answer (score 0):

1. Seems like `Map`, which from you retrieving values is `nullable`.
2. `Opacity` widget has required field `opacity`, which cannot be `null`
3. `Offset` has required field too, which also cannot be `null`

So you have to convert these values to non nullabe, for example:

```
  Opacity(
    opacity: animation?["opacity"] ?? .1, //we return default value (any suitable default value, for example 0.1) if animation["opacity"] returns null
    child: Transform.translate(
        offset: Offset(0, animation?["translateY"] ?? .1), child: child), //same
  )
```

Comment: Hi thanks or your attention... but it doesnt work ......it says : error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.  how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: i guess the main problem is this : info: The library  package:simple_animations/simple_animations.dart' is legacy, and should not be imported into a null safe library.  I have to change the version or code .......